# unknown dateTime difference between typescript and java

Tags: java, angular

i am creating a project in angular and spring boot.

upon a certain event i send a date type object (called start time) from angular  to spring boot which is written is in java
i am facing 2 problems:

1. when i send the startTime from angular it is sent in indian standard time.
   but when i receive the start time in the back-end it is stored in utc format so there is -5.30 time difference
2. when i bring back the startTime at time of login (from back-end) i can display it in form of console.log(startTime) but when i do startTime.getHours(),startTime.getMinutes() etc.
   it shows an error that the getHours() is not a function of startTime

guys can anyone help me with both of the problem..

here is my scheduleData.ts which has startTime

```
export class scheduleData {
    public StartTime: Date;
    public EndTime: Date;
}
```

now here is my java code

```
public class ScheduleDataModel {

    public LocalDateTime StartTime;
    public LocalDateTime EndTime;

}
```

Comment: Use ZonedDateTime?

Comment: @GetMeARemoteJob i tried to it but not able to implement it..and what about the second problem

Comment: when you get it back from server, you need to parse it again to a date object.

Comment: so in between do i have to send it in a string form?

Comment: you will get it in a string form on the client side, you are using LocalDateTime so you should get something like `"2020-05-16T21:20:54.624"`, just do new Date("2020-05-16T21:20:54.624") and then call `.getHours()` or whatever date method you want.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase.

Comment: @MCEmperor thank you i will take care of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) If you send or receive a date, the informaton is sent as a date string. 
In most cases it's a part of a json.
You must always send (or get) a timezone.

2.) You get a string. You have to parse it:

```
const d = new Date(yourDateString);
```